# How to use rewrite the cart/item/default.phtml template file to my module in Magento2

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart

I have my cutom module and i need to write my own item/defult.phtml to my custom module template path how to do it ?

i saw one getOverriddenTemplates, how to return the value so that my custom file can take

Answer (score 5):

i used plugin for this and it working fine

in di.xml

```
 <type name="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\AbstractCart">
    <plugin name="item-test" type="YOURNAMESPACE\Checkout\Block\AbstractCart" sortOrder="1"/>
</type>



class AbstractCart
{
    public function afterGetItemRenderer(\Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\AbstractCart $subject, $result)
    {
    $result->setTemplate('YOURNAMESPACE_Checkout::cart/item/default.phtml');
    return $result;
    }
}
```

this works fine but i feel by using injection concept or virtual type we can return the value for getOverriddenTemplates() then that is better option
it should return the value some thing like below

and return value should be return ['simple'=>'test2.phtml'];

so if any one know post it :-)

Comment: its the only way that worked with me , thanks

Comment: Its woking for me.but also i override edit.phtml  how?

Comment: it was working with magento 2.1.x and 2.2.x version but not works in magento 2.3.x version