# Magento2 custom module overrides layout: The element "checkout.cart.item.renderers" already has a child with alias "simple" in exception log

Tags: magento2, checkout, layout, exception

In a custom module I override the cart item template. It works, but my exception log is filling up with `The element "checkout.cart.item.renderers" already has a child with alias "default"` and `alias "simple"` errors.

How do I correct my code to fix this?

In my custom module I have the file `app/code/MyCompany/MyModule/view/frontend/layout/checkout_cart_item_renderers.xml` with the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.item.renderers">
            <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer" as="default" template="MyCompany_MyModule::cart/item/default.phtml">
                <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer\Actions" name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.default.actions" as="actions">
                    <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer\Actions\Edit" name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.default.actions.edit" template="Magento_Checkout::cart/item/renderer/actions/edit.phtml"/>
                    <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer\Actions\Remove" name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.default.actions.remove" template="Magento_Checkout::cart/item/renderer/actions/remove.phtml"/>
                </block>
            </block>
            <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer" as="simple" template="MyCompany_MyModule::cart/item/default.phtml">
                <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer\Actions" name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.simple.actions" as="actions">
                    <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer\Actions\Edit" name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.simple.actions.edit" template="Magento_Checkout::cart/item/renderer/actions/edit.phtml"/>
                    <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer\Actions\Remove" name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.simple.actions.remove" template="Magento_Checkout::cart/item/renderer/actions/remove.phtml"/>
                </block>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

My custom template is in `/app/code/MyCompany/MyModule/view/frontend/templates/cart/item/default.phtml`.

I have tried removing the block first, then it doesn't load anything. Any help how to do this the right way is appreciated.

Comment: what do you want to do, plz specify in details.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, the question is clear: overriding the template works, but it fills up my exception log, so obviously it is not the right way to do it.

Comment: you can override your phtml file inside theme folder and check chagnes.

Answer (score 8):

My version override based of method `getItemRenderer` of `Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\AbstractCart`, used variable `OverriddenTemplates`.

file `vendor/module/view/frontend/layout/checkout_cart_item_renderers.xml`

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<!-- override checkout cart item template -->
<referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.form">
    <action method="setOverriddenTemplates">
        <argument xsi:type="array">
            <!-- list override templates -->
            <item name="default" xsi:type="string">vendor_module::cart/item/default.phtml</item>
            <item name="simple" xsi:type="string">vendor_module::cart/item/default.phtml</item>
            <item name="virtual" xsi:type="string">vendor_module::cart/item/default.phtml</item>
        </argument>
    </action>
</referenceBlock>
```

Also see [Complete code sample](https://github.com/karliuka/magento2.samples/tree/master/app/code/Faonni/OverrideCartItemTemplate) on GitHub

Comment: This is the correct solution, nothing else I tried worked. Also works for configurable products, which is what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that the following blocks are already declared by core files of Magento 2:

- `default`
- `simple`

As you only want to change the template I suggest you do the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.item.renderers">
            <referenceBlock name="default" template="MyCompany_MyModule::cart/item/default.phtml" />
            <referenceBlock name="simple" template="MyCompany_MyModule::cart/item/default.phtml" />
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Alternatively you can also do:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.item.renderers">
            <referenceBlock name="default">
                <action method="setTemplate">
                    <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">MyCompany_MyModule::cart/item/default.phtml</argument>
                </action>
            </referenceBlock>
            <referenceBlock name="simple">
                <action method="setTemplate">
                    <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">MyCompany_MyModule::cart/item/default.phtml</argument>
                </action>
            </referenceBlock>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but neither of these methods work. They do not override the template file.

Comment: @tecjam see my edited code for the right code, I missed a line -_-

Comment: This still does not work for me.

Comment: @tecjam try deleting both `var/cache` and `var/generation` folders and double check as it's definitely the right way to go

Comment: I run: `rm -rf var/* ` and `php bin:magento cache:clean` and `php bin:magento cache:flush` and manually delete pub/static/frontend - this makes not difference as the template is not overridden. My above code however works, apart from writing exception logs. I guess I'll just have to live with the exception logs until I find a working solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is working code for module `default.phtml` file override,

Below step by step code for this functionality,

I have changed block name `checkout.cart.item.renderers.override` so we have to override `checkout_cart_index.xml` file

**registration.php** file,

Full path,

```
app/code/Package/Modulename/registration.php
```

code for this,

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Package_Modulename',
    __DIR__
);
```

**composer.json** file,

```
app/code/Package/Modulename/composer.json
```

composer declaration,

```
{
    "name": "package/magento2-modulename",
    "description": "module desctiption",
    "require": {
        "php": "~5.5.0|~5.6.0"
    },
    "type": "magento2-module",
    "version": "1.4.0",
    "license": [
        "OSL-3.0",
        "AFL-3.0"
    ],
    "extra": {
        "map": [
            [
                "*",
                "Package/Modulename"
            ]
        ]
    }
}
```

`module.xml file`,

Full path,
`app/code/Package/Modulename/etc/module.xml` file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
        <module name="Package_Modulename" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
                <module name="Magento_Checkout"/>
            </sequence>
        </module>
    </config>
```

Override checkout_cart_index.xml file from core,

```
app/code/Package/Modulename/view/frontend/layout/checkout_cart_index.xml
```

Keep below code,

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
        <body>
                <referenceBlock class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart" name="checkout.cart.form" as="cart-items" template="cart/form.phtml">
                    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\RendererList" name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.override" as="renderer.list.custom"/>
                </referenceBlock>
        </body>
    </page>
```

**checkout_cart_item_renderers.xml file,**
file path location, `app/code/Package/Modulename/view/frontend/layout/checkout_cart_item_renderers.xml`

xml code for override **default.phtml** file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.override">
            <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer" as="default" template="Package_Modulename::cart/item/default.phtml">
                <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer\Actions" name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.default.actions" as="actions">
                    <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer\Actions\Edit" name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.default.actions.edit" template="Magento_Checkout::cart/item/renderer/actions/edit.phtml"/>
                    <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer\Actions\Remove" name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.default.actions.remove" template="Magento_Checkout::cart/item/renderer/actions/remove.phtml"/>
                </block>
            </block>
            <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer" as="simple" template="Package_Modulename::cart/item/default.phtml">
                <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer\Actions" name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.simple.actions" as="actions">
                    <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer\Actions\Edit" name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.simple.actions.edit" template="Magento_Checkout::cart/item/renderer/actions/edit.phtml"/>
                    <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer\Actions\Remove" name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.simple.actions.remove" template="Magento_Checkout::cart/item/renderer/actions/remove.phtml"/>
                </block>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

`template file`,

```
app/code/Vendor/Age/view/frontend/templates/cart/item/default.phtml
```

Code for template,

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

/** @var $block \Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer */

$_item = $block->getItem();
$product = $_item->getProduct();
$isVisibleProduct = $product->isVisibleInSiteVisibility();
/** @var \Magento\Msrp\Helper\Data $helper */
$helper = $this->helper('Magento\Msrp\Helper\Data');
$canApplyMsrp = $helper->isShowBeforeOrderConfirm($product) && $helper->isMinimalPriceLessMsrp($product);
?>
1111111111111111111111111111111111
<tbody class="cart item">
    <tr class="item-info">
        <td data-th="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Item')); ?>" class="col item">
            <?php if ($block->hasProductUrl()):?>
                <a href="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getProductUrl() ?>"
                   title="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getProductName()) ?>"
                   tabindex="-1"
                   class="product-item-photo">
            <?php else:?>
                <span class="product-item-photo">
            <?php endif;?>
            <?php echo $block->getImage($block->getProductForThumbnail(), 'cart_page_product_thumbnail')->toHtml(); ?>
            <?php if ($block->hasProductUrl()):?>
                </a>
            <?php else: ?>
                </span>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <div class="product-item-details">
                <strong class="product-item-name">
                    <?php if ($block->hasProductUrl()):?>
                        <a href="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getProductUrl() ?>"><?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getProductName()) ?></a>
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getProductName()) ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </strong>
                <?php if ($_options = $block->getOptionList()):?>
                    <dl class="item-options">
                        <?php foreach ($_options as $_option) : ?>
                            <?php $_formatedOptionValue = $block->getFormatedOptionValue($_option) ?>
                            <dt><?php echo $block->escapeHtml($_option['label']) ?></dt>
                            <dd>
                                <?php if (isset($_formatedOptionValue['full_view'])): ?>
                                    <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_formatedOptionValue['full_view'] ?>
                                <?php else: ?>
                                    <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_formatedOptionValue['value'] ?>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            </dd>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </dl>
                <?php endif;?>
                <?php if ($messages = $block->getMessages()): ?>
                    <?php foreach ($messages as $message): ?>
                        <div class="cart item message <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $message['type'] ?>"><div><?php echo $block->escapeHtml($message['text']) ?></div></div>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php $addInfoBlock = $block->getProductAdditionalInformationBlock(); ?>
                <?php if ($addInfoBlock): ?>
                    <?php echo $addInfoBlock->setItem($_item)->toHtml() ?>
                <?php endif;?>
            </div>
        </td>

        <?php if ($canApplyMsrp): ?>
            <td class="col msrp" data-th="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Price')); ?>">
                <span class="pricing msrp">
                    <span class="msrp notice"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('See price before order confirmation.'); ?></span>
                    <?php $helpLinkId = 'cart-msrp-help-' . $_item->getId(); ?>
                    <a href="#" class="action help map" id="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo($helpLinkId); ?>" data-mage-init='{"addToCart":{"helpLinkId": "#<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $helpLinkId;?>","productName": "<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $product->getName(); ?>","showAddToCart": false}}'>
                        <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __("What's this?"); ?></span>
                    </a>
                </span>
            </td>
        <?php else: ?>
            <td class="col price" data-th="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Price')); ?>">
                <?php echo $block->getUnitPriceHtml($_item); ?>
            </td>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <td class="col qty" data-th="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Qty')); ?>">
            <div class="field qty">
                <label class="label" for="cart-<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_item->getId() ?>-qty">
                    <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Qty') ?></span>
                </label>
                <div class="control qty">
                    <input id="cart-<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_item->getId() ?>-qty"
                           name="cart[<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_item->getId() ?>][qty]"
                           data-cart-item-id="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_item->getSku() ?>"
                           value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getQty() ?>"
                           type="number"
                           size="4"
                           title="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Qty')); ?>"
                           class="input-text qty"
                           maxlength="12"
                           data-validate="{required:true,'validate-greater-than-zero':true}"
                           data-role="cart-item-qty"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>

        <td class="col subtotal" data-th="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Subtotal'));?>">
            <?php if ($canApplyMsrp): ?>
                <span class="cart msrp subtotal">--</span>
            <?php else: ?>
                <?php echo $block->getRowTotalHtml($_item); ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="item-actions">
        <td colspan="100">
            <div class="actions-toolbar">
                <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getActions($_item) ?>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Now you have to just **override core block**

> function _getRendererList()

from  `Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\AbstractCart.php` file.

code for function,

```
protected function _getRendererList()
    {
        echo 'tets';exit;
        return $this->getRendererListName() ? $this->getLayout()->getBlock(
            $this->getRendererListName()
        ) : $this->getChildBlock(
            'renderer.list.custom'
        );
    }
```

Check above code in your case.

plz after apply above code just run command,

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

remove **var** folder and browser cache.

This is working code and you can check after `var/exception.log` no any error or notice generate.

Plz let me know if any issue occours.

Comment: Hi @Rakesh, while I appreaciate the answer and the above code works (my module does it the exact same way!!) please have a look into your var/exception.log file and you will see the exception error this question is all about.

Comment: I have update my answer. plz refer again and check your exception.log file.

Comment: Hi, your above code works, but I'm overriding only checkout_onepage_success.xml file in my custom theme and still I'm getting the exception that is mentioned in the question. Do you have any idea regarding this?

Comment: @RakeshJesadiya But somehow Configurable options not display in cart page item.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this using Raphael's second suggestion (action setTemplate) combined with a custom Cart/Item/Renderer Block:

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Block;
class CartItemRenderer extends Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer
{
// I have made no customizations yet.
}
```

And using frontend/di.xml to replace Magento_Checkout default:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer" 
                type="Vendor\Module\Block\CartItemRenderer"/>
</config>
```

--
**[Update 2016-07-08]**
After looking into it some more, I realized that the setTemplate action is never used because the renderer name (eg, "simple") is really an *alias*, not a *name*, and Magento 2 requires the *name* in referenceBlock. The only reason the method I stated above worked is because the "simple" and "default" renderers use a relative template path (cart/item/default.phtml instead of Magento_Checkout::cart/item/default.phtml), so by changing the class block, you change the relative folder (from Magento/Checkout to Vendor/Module). This solution does not work for any of the other types ("configurable", "grouped", etc.).

TLDR; there is currently no way in layout xml to override the individual renderer templates in Magento 2. You will have to resort to theme changes, and/or do it in a Plugin intercept (helpful example here - it worked for me: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/112485/41862).