# How to use rewrite the cart/item/default.phtml template file my module?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

First I overwrite checkout_cart_index.xml in my module like below

> app/code/Custom/Module/view/frontend/layout/checkout_cart_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart" name="checkout.cart.form">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\RendererList" name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.override" as="renderer.list.custom"/>
            <arguments>
                <argument name="renderer_list_name" xsi:type="string">checkout.cart.item.renderers.override</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Then I overwrite

> checkout_cart_item_renderers.xml

in my module like below

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
<referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.override">
            <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer" as="default" template="Custom_Module::cart/item/default.phtml" />              
            <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer" as="simple" template="Custom_Module::cart/item/default.phtml" />  
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Then I overwrite default.phtml file under below path

> app/code/Custom/Module/view/frontend/templates/cart/item/default.phtml

After doing this I run below Command also:

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

I am getting below error in checkout page:-
`

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'referenceBlock', attribute 'class': The attribute 'class' is not allowed.
Line: 1478
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'referenceBlock', attribute 'class': The attribute 'class' is not allowed.
Line: 1478
#0 /home/193246.cloudwaysapps.com/zqesqtynyy/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Config/Dom.php(115): Magento\Framework\Config\Dom->_initDom('<layout xmlns:x...')
#1 /home/193246.cloudwaysapps.com/zqesqtynyy/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(111): Magento\Framework\Config\Dom->__construct('<layout xmlns:x...', Object(Magento\Framework\App\Arguments\ValidationState), Array, NULL, '/home/193246.cl...', '%message%\nLine:...')
#2 /home/193246.cloudwaysapps.com/zqesqtynyy/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(108): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('Magento\\Framewo...', Array)
#3 /home/193246.cloudwaysapps.com/zqesqtynyy/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(56): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create('Magento\\Framewo...', Array)
#4 /home/193246.cloudwaysapps.com/zqesqtynyy/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Config/DomFactory.php(42): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create('Magento\\Framewo...', Array)
#5 /home/193246.cloudwaysapps.com/zqesqtynyy/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Model/Layout/Update/Validator.php(141): Magento\Framework\Config\DomFactory->createDom(Array)
#6 /home/193246.cloudwaysapps.com/zqesqtynyy/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Model/Layout/Merge.php(461): Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Update\Validator->isValid('<layout xmlns:x...', 'layout_merged', false)
#7 /home/193246.cloudwaysapps.com/zqesqtynyy/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Model/Layout/Merge.php(442): Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Merge->_validateMergedLayout('LAYOUT_frontend...', '<body>\n   <refe...')
#8 /home/193246.cloudwaysapps.com/zqesqtynyy/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php(86): Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Merge->load()
#9 /home/193246.cloudwaysapps.com/zqesqtynyy/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php(63): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->loadLayoutUpdates()
#10 /home/193246.cloudwaysapps.com/zqesqtynyy/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Config.php(197): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->build()
#11 /home/193246.cloudwaysapps.com/zqesqtynyy/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Config.php(217): Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config->build()
#12 /home/193246.cloudwaysapps.com/zqesqtynyy/public_html/vendor/magento/module-checkout/Controller/Cart/Index.php(55): Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config->getTitle()
#13 /home/193246.cloudwaysapps.com/zqesqtynyy/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Index->execute()
#14 /home/193246.cloudwaysapps.com/zqesqtynyy/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Index\Interceptor->___callParent('execute', Array)
#15 /home/193246.cloudwaysapps.com/zqesqtynyy/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Index\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#16 /home/193246.cloudwaysapps.com/zqesqtynyy/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Checkout/Controller/Cart/Index/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Index\Interceptor->___callPlugins('execute', Array, Array)
#17 /home/193246.cloudwaysapps.com/zqesqtynyy/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php(107): Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Index\Interceptor->execute()
#18 /home/193246.cloudwaysapps.com/zqesqtynyy/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#19 /home/193246.cloudwaysapps.com/zqesqtynyy/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Index\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#20 /home/193246.cloudwaysapps.com/zqesqtynyy/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Index\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#21 /home/193246.cloudwaysapps.com/zqesqtynyy/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Checkout/Controller/Cart/Index/Interceptor.php(39): Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Index\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#22 /home/193246.cloudwaysapps.com/zqesqtynyy/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(55): Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Index\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#23 /home/193246.cloudwaysapps.com/zqesqtynyy/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#24 /home/193246.cloudwaysapps.com/zqesqtynyy/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#25 /home/193246.cloudwaysapps.com/zqesqtynyy/public_html/vendor/magento/module-store/App/FrontController/Plugin/RequestPreprocessor.php(94): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#26 /home/193246.cloudwaysapps.com/zqesqtynyy/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\Store\App\FrontController\Plugin\RequestPreprocessor->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#27 /home/193246.cloudwaysapps.com/zqesqtynyy/public_html/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/BuiltinPlugin.php(69): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#28 /home/193246.cloudwaysapps.com/zqesqtynyy/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#29 /home/193246.cloudwaysapps.com/zqesqtynyy/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#30 /home/193246.cloudwaysapps.com/zqesqtynyy/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, NULL)
#31 /home/193246.cloudwaysapps.com/zqesqtynyy/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#32 /home/193246.cloudwaysapps.com/zqesqtynyy/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(256): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#33 /home/193246.cloudwaysapps.com/zqesqtynyy/public_html/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor))
#34 {main}
```

Comment: If your purpose is to set custom template file, then you can used settemplate method of block.

Comment: @DhirenVasoya  I used plugin also, but I am not able to overwrite successfully.

Comment: @DhirenVasoya I followed below link but still no luck
https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/how-to-override-cart-item-default-phtml-in-magento-2/

Answer (score 1):

You are adding the same class twice

> checkout_cart_item_renderers.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
<referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.override">
            <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer" as="default" template="Custom_Module::cart/item/default.phtml" />              
            <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer" as="simple" template="Custom_Module::cart/item/default.phtml" />  
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Remove it

`<block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer" as="simple" template="Custom_Module::cart/item/default.phtml" />`

Will be something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.override">
            <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer" as="default" template="Custom_Module::cart/item/default.phtml">
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Run commands

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Test it.

Check Rakesh override for more info: [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/112858/magento2-custom-module-overrides-layout-the-element-checkout-cart-item-rendere)

Comment: after deleting the line also getting same error

Comment: do a rm -rf generated/* rm -rf pub/static/* , run the above commands

Comment: Yes, I run below command also:-
rm -rf generated/ ,
rm -rf pub/static/frontend/ ,
rm -rf var/
but no luck

Comment: correct the tags also , updated my answer

Comment: Not understand which tag are you talking about?

Comment: the block tag </block>

Comment: the error fixed but overwrite not working

Comment: than you can open another ticket for that :), if this worked for you please accept as an answer

Comment: I want to add below condition before qty section <?php if ($isVisibleProduct): ?>

Comment: What about the checkout_cart_index.xml  this file, I need to add </block>  also or not

Comment: No need to add for that.