# How to get Current Product Id in which the Block is Rendered?

Tags: magento2, product, blocks, phtml

I have made a custom Block that appears on the checkout page of every product item. So each time the product is rendered, that block is called.[image] The block is rendered below every product item. I want to get the current product id on which the block is trying to render in a phtml file. So if I can get the current product id of that item, I can check some conditions and render that block based on those conditions. So it will not render on all products on the checkout page.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Please share your Block, Layout and phtml file here for a better answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer worked for me. I overrode the default.phtml file with my logic and it worked as I wanted.

This is the link to the answer I followed.
https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/212004/108564